# SQL Server : Left Join using 1 = 1

Tags: sql-server, left-join

My application is developed using framework so I need to follow some structure which can't be changed.

In SQL Server, I need to achieve [inner join using left join which is possible using 1=1](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/25/sql-server-inner-join-using-left-join-statement-performance-analysis/)

Now in my case there is an `Account` table with few details, and `account_ext` table with a few more columns of account related information.

There is an `ACCT_NAME_LNK` table which has link to particular name to particular account and it has expiry date also

Now I need to fetch all records which has link to name link table and acct table

My conditions is it should not show expired records and in or condition  `T2.AcctHDDescription like '6%'`

This means there should be link to name or `ACCTHDDescription` should like `'6%'`

So it should not show expired record but it is showing

Below is my query

```
DECLARE @EXPDATE DATETIME 
SET @EXPDATE = GETDATE()

SELECT DISTINCT   
    T1.ID, T1.AccountID, T2.AcctHDDescription 
FROM 
    ACCT T1 
LEFT JOIN  
    ACCT_Ext T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
LEFT JOIN  
    ACCT_NAME_LNK T3 ON 1 = 1 
                     AND ISNULL(T3.EXPIRED, '2999-12-31') > @EXPDATE
WHERE
    T1.ID = T3.acctid OR T2.AcctHDDescription LIKE '6%'
```

Added one more image with more details
I need to achieve the output using left join on 1=1
And it has Or condition

[{Link available and not expired} or {AcctHDDescription = '6%'}]

[Latest Image which shows output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcacS.jpg)

Expected output
Id  AccountId   AcctHDDDescription
3   33333   1234
4   62343   345
6   624323  6667

Comment: Yes it has two conditions i. there can be a link with name if link is there then it should consider the expiry date of that link               [OR] ii. AcctHddDescription ='6%' , so if 6% record has link with name it should consider expiry date if there is no link it should not consider and should come in the result set all this has to be achieved using left join 1=1

Comment: Please edit your question to incorporate clarifications. Comments are ephemeral & not for clarifications. Don't use links/images unless all possible text content in it is *also* in your question *as text*. (Format code & tables as code.) Please read & act on [mcve]. PS Your clarification is hard to follow & is not grammatical. Please use more, simpler sentences.

Comment: You are not clear. What do you mean, "I need to achieve inner join using left join"? What do you think the benefit of `left join on 1=1` is? Why did you give that link? What does "I need to follow some structure which can't be changed." mean? Do you mean you are building different queries like this? (Other than via `@EXPDATE`.) What is the form of input tables? Yes `left join on (true and ...)` is `left join on ...` and `left join on true` (also `inner join on true`) is `cross join`. But so what? Explain clearly what you want. Don't use too few words. Give example input & desired output.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bit of a strange query but I think your issue lies in the WHERE clause OR condition.  My initial guess is you want to move the ID join into the left join:

```
declare @EXPDATE datetime
set @EXPDATE=GETDATE()

SELECT DISTINCT   T1.ID,T1.AccountID ,T2.AcctHDDescription 
FROM ACCT T1 LEFT JOIN  ACCT_Ext  T2 ON T1.ID  = T2.ID 
LEFT JOIN  ACCT_NAME_LNK  T3 ON 1  = 1 
   AND ISNULL( T3.EXPIRED, '2999-12-31' ) > @EXPDATE
   AND T1.ID = T3.acctid
where  T2.AcctHDDescription like '6%'
```

Comment: Yes it has two conditions i. there can be a link with name if link is there then it should consider the expiry date of that link               [OR] ii. AcctHddDescription ='6%' , so if 6% record has link with name it should consider expiry date if there is no link it should not consider and should come in the result set all this has to be achieved using left join 1=1

Comment: I too suspect that this (less the `1=1 and`) is what @user3394295 needs but when a question is unclear it should be downvoted, close voted & commented on asking for clarification, not answered. Also there is no point to putting `1=1` in your answer without clarification from the OP (like they need a query template that will work with an arbitrary number of conjuncts, although there is no hint of such need, including given their link, and probably they are just confused, about what to put in `on` vs `where`), and you don't address it.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing what you want,

```
DECLARE @EXPDATE DATETIME
SET @EXPDATE=GETDATE();

SELECT T1.ID
    , T1.AccountID  
    , T2.AcctHDDescription 
    , T3.Expired
FROM Acct T1 
LEFT JOIN  Acct_Ext  T2 
    ON T1.ID  = T2.ID 
LEFT JOIN ACCT_NAME_LNK  T3 
        ON T1.ID = T3.acctid
WHERE  (T2.AcctHDDescription like '6%' AND ISNULL(T3.EXPIRED, '2999-12-31' ) > @EXPDATE)
OR ISNULL( T3.EXPIRED, '2999-12-31' ) > @EXPDATE;
```

Comment: Yes it has two conditions i. there can be a link with name if link is there then it should consider the expiry date of that link               [OR] ii. AcctHddDescription ='6%' , so if 6% record has link with name it should consider expiry date if there is no link it should not consider and should come in the result set all this has to be achieved using left join 1=1

Comment: Please post with your 3 tables' structure and sample data.

Comment: See my comment on Jesse's answer.